# JsonObjectRequest - cannot send arguments

Tags: php, android, http-post, jsonobjectrequest

I am not sure why I cannot get the correct response from my PHP code. For my PHP code, it is really simple. It should just return the POST arguments. But in my Android project, it returns null for all arguments. I tried to test the PHP code in my iOS project. Everything works perfect. It returns `["target": zh, "arrayString": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000000192a0>(hello world), "source": en]` So, I guess maybe my Android project has some problems then I tried to create a new project and do it again, but still hitting the same issue. Below is the steps for my new Android project.

Build Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String requestString = "http://ddoommaaiinn.com/testPost.php";
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
        try {
            parameters.put("source", "en");
            parameters.put("target", "zh");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray.put("hello world");
            parameters.put("stringArray", jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("JSONParams", parameters.toString());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestString, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //TODO: handle success
                Log.d("successful", response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
    }
}
```

Debug

```
12-27 08:47:19.994 4363-4363/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/JSONParams: {"source":"en","target":"zh","stringArray":["hello world"]}
12-27 08:47:20.050 4363-4395/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
12-27 08:47:20.079 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
12-27 08:47:20.885 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
12-27 08:47:20.886 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-27 08:47:20.886 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-27 08:47:20.886 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-27 08:47:20.886 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
12-27 08:47:20.892 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa6f859e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
12-27 08:47:20.895 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f859e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb050d880)
12-27 08:47:20.998 4363-4397/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f859e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb050d880)
12-27 08:47:21.279 4363-4363/com.pakhocheung.testjsonobjectrequest D/successful: {"source":null,"target":null,"arrayString":null}
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$source = $_POST['source'];
$target = $_POST['target'];
$arrayString = $_POST['stringArray'];
echo json_encode(array('source'=>$source,'target'=>$target,'arrayString'=>$arrayString));
?>
```

Comment: try `$postArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`, then `$source = $postArray['source']` and so on. Or better do a `var_dump($postArray)` after first line.

Comment: Once I use ```$postArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);, then $source = $postArray['source']``` I can get the correct result. Thanks a lot

Comment: then I'll add this as an answer! Fell free to accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `JsonObjectRequest` the desired data would be found in `php://input` as a (json) string. To get that data do:

```
<?php
$postArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

// now you access the values nearly as before:
$source = $postArray['source'];
$target = $postArray['target'];
$arrayString = $postArray['arrayString'];

echo json_encode(array('source'=>$source,'target'=>$target,'arrayString'=>$arrayString));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you $_POST is not working

for testing try will hardcoded value

```
$source = 'test';
$target = 'test-target';
$arrayString = 'test-arrayString';

echo json_encode(array('source'=>$source,'target'=>$target,'arrayString'=>$arrayString));
```

it should give following json

```
{"source":"test","target":"test-target","arrayString":"test-arrayString"}
```

please add if anything is missing

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i can delete it  the ans, formating comment difficult :( . let me know what to do

Comment: leave it for now, think about it next time if your valueable contribution is already an answer!

Comment: Got the correct result by using ```$postArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);, then $source = $postArray['source']``` Thanks for the help